# Getting entities with dashes

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I am trying to get an entity that contains dashes, it's a product id.  Even though I have trained LUIS with samples that have dashes it only returns the characters up to the first dash.  For example ABC123-100 returns ABC123.  How can I get LUIS to recognize the whole ID?

Comment: Did Haritha's answer help with your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a "pattern Feature" and define the entity patterns that you need to identify as the entity. That'll solve your problem[image]